# Subclassing or not?

Tags: java, object-oriented, classes

I have a class called `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
    private String optionalProperty;
    private String name;
    private long uniqueId;
    // getters/setters for above properties
}
```

For some business reason I need to create an Identifier which I can use to 'identify' Foo instances (having some `name`/`uniqueId`) in some business flow. I want to create some `FooIdentifier` class which will be used to identify `Foo` instances (this `FooIdentifier` has other business use cases as well and this is one of the use cases).

Since this `FooIdentifier` will be either based on `name` or `uniqueId` we need to distinguish between those two scenarios, `optionalProperty` is common in both the scenarios.
I'm considering two designs as follows -
Subclassing -

```
public abstract class FooIdentifier {

        private String optionalProperty;

        public enum Type {
            NAME_BASED, ID_BASED
        }

        protected FooIdentifier(String optionalProperty) {
            this.optionalProperty = optionalProperty;
        }

        public String getOptionalProperty() {
            return optionalProperty;
        }

        public abstract Type getType();

    }

    public class NameBasedIdentifier extends FooIdentifier {
        private String name;

        public NameBasedIdentifier(String optionalProperty, String name) {
            super(optionalProperty);
            this.name = name;
        }

        public NameBasedIdentifier(String name) {
            this(null, name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override public Type getType() {
            return Type.NAME_BASED;
        }
    }

    public class IdBasedIdentifier extends FooIdentifier {
        private long uniqueId;

        public IdBasedIdentifier(String optionalProperty, long uniqueId) {
            super(optionalProperty);
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        }

        public IdBasedIdentifier(long uniqueId) {
            this(null, uniqueId);
        }

        public long getUniqueId() {
            return uniqueId;
        }

        @Override public Type getType() {
            return Type.ID_BASED;
        }
    }
```

Or plain old class -

```
public class FooIdentifier {

        private String optionalProperty;
        private String name;
        private long uniqueId;

        public enum Type {
            NAME_BASED, ID_BASED
        }

        public FooIdentifier(String optionalProperty, String name) {
            this.optionalProperty = optionalProperty;
            this.name = name; // will have null check
        }

        public FooIdentifier(String optionalProperty, long uniqueId) {
            this.optionalProperty = optionalProperty;
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId; // will have null check
        }

        public FooIdentifier(String name) {
            this(null, name);
        }

        public FooIdentifier(long uniqueId) {
            this(null, uniqueId);
        }

        public String getOptionalProperty() {
            return optionalProperty;
        }

        public Type getType() {
            return name == null ? Type.ID_BASED : Type.NAME_BASED;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getUniqueId() {
            return uniqueId;
        }    
    }
```

Which one will be better?

Comment: Did you ever decide on an approach for this?

Comment: yes, I went with One public class and private inner classes for all the special implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to retrieve the string or long values (I don't see getters for them in the single class) I prefer the three classes, with the getter methods also in the base class to avoid a cast. Each derived class would unconditionally throw an exception if the inappropriate getter method is called, whereas a single class needs an if statement in both getters. Same goes for if you added a toString() method, equals(long), equals(string) or other methods to the base class - no if statements for "which type of class am I" that are necessary with a single class.

Comment: So basically you're saying I should have three classes but subclasses should not be visible to the clients and all clients will deal with main `FooIdentifier` class.. right?

Comment: Yes. Ideally there would be some way to use them without ever having to call getType(). Like a toString() method that converted the long to a string if necessary for accessing the data and an equals( FooIdentifer in) method for comparing them. But maybe getType() is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

The *old class* is interesting : 
you can have a double identification, with *name* and *long* (`long` is never `null` but `0L`) for the same 'user', so you will be able to know it.
However if a same 'user' may have two entries, two identities it does not matter, and *three class* is loosely coupled, if those classes engage opposite traitements, why not.